# Owin startup happens more than once

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, owin

In a web api 2 application we develop, when running the web server, for some reason Owin Startup method happens more than once. Is there a specific cause for this? Where should I look into in order to prevent it?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe you call in the construcor a method and call this class method somewhere else again? - hard to say without debugging

Comment: It's the first line in code, no one calls it. Only running the application should cause reaching those lines. I'm pretty sure it's bad configuration or aomething, can't figure it out yet

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint when it starts up and check the call stack window on each time it stops on the breakpoint. This will tell you where it is getting called from.

I have also seen this happen when you have added the [OWIN startup detection](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection) set up and you also add in an explicit start up in code - for example in your WebApi config. Ordering could also be a problem.

Comment: But it is the top root of the application, the first line that runs, no one calls it from the code

Comment: Are you saying in you break and look at Environment.StackTrace it has nothing in it bar the ctor? I would have thought you would see framework components / packages higher in the stack.

Comment: Add a second thought in my answer.

Comment: For startup detection I use the attribute approach. What are you suggesting that could be wrong with the web.config?

Answer (score 0):

Check Assembly attribute added in class so first it registered owin and then fire and it is static too

Comment: I have attribute to detect the Owin startup. Could you explain in more details, what exactly do you mean?